# Can't compile C++ with QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to compile a piece of example c++ code from qt.io:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  QApplication app (argc, argv);
  return app.exec();
}
```

I then did `qmake`. With a qt.pro containing the following:

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += gui declarative
SOURCES += qt.cpp
```

When I then do a `make` it gives the following error:

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o qt qt.o    -L/usr/lib64/qt4 -lQtDeclarative -lQtGui -L/usr/lib64/qt4 -lQtCore -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtDeclarative
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'qt' failed
make: *** [qt] Error 1
```

I am using funtoo linux

Comment: Perhaps when you compiled Qt on funtoo you did not build QtDeclarative. It should be `dev-qt/qtdeclarative` I believe (I use gentoo not funtoo) you can check with `equery list qtde*`

Comment: remove `declarative` from your .pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following AMA's comment, I removed declarative from my qt.pro. This solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah `declarative` is overrated anyway! On a serious note: make sure all qt libraries you need are build. Since QtDeclarative is not there something might be wrong.

Comment: In gentoo this (QtDeclarative) is optional. I believe funtoo will be the same.